# ffmpeg h264_vaapi video encoding

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, h.264

it look like ffmpeg and h264_vaapi codec are broken in the newest version 4 because they don’t honor the -qp setting. -qp with any value don’t change the bitrate which is terrible high. Only setting the bitrate option directly -b works. Does someone know a way around it.

Problem could be replicated with simple command:
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i input.mp4 -vf ‘format=nv12,hwupload’ -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 30 output.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was repaired in [ffmpeg's commit f4d7bd6cdbcf9027a36a73531baf7e3885644ee6](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/f4d7bd6cdbcf9027a36a73531baf7e3885644ee6) and unfortunately that commit is still only available in the git master branch.  Hopefully it will be part of ffmpeg-4.1.2; backporting that commit to earlier versions looks like a huge undertaking.

Until ffmpeg-4.1.2 you can either compile the git master yourself, or [install a nightly build](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) from the ffmpeg site.

[2019/03/27 edit: ffmpeg-4.1.2 was released without that commit; it appears to be destined for ffmpeg-4.2 unfortunately.]